# How to add a shared library in configure?

Tags: compiling

I am having a very hard time to install kmscon in a centos server.
Everything was fixed , until i reached the libtsm library, which ksmcon requires.
Then when I started dealing with it, it seams it get installed , but also need to get linked to. The instructions to link this library are here, but could not do so.. I do not understand how (This is after `make install`:
[image]

This is in the case of libtsm. When trying to configure kmscon, which require the previous one, I am of course stuck in here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, at least I past the problem of libtsm.

libtsm was installed separately but was needed to link to before running ./configure.

Even though the /usr/local/lib was the installation folder, /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig was the PKG_CONFIG_PATH that I needed to `export`.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
./configure
```

That was all.